# servlet and mysql display error

Tags: mysql, servlets

im currently trying to make a servlet that connects to a mysql database and display the contents.so far i have everything goin great, excpet one problem. When if log in it grabs the notes in the datbase and it displays them. if i logout and login again , it displays the same data again. so it displays the the data twice. if i log in with another user, it displays those previous 2 and the new users data. so i dont know why its doin this. i dont know if its a session thing or what. below is my java and jsp files

```
@WebServlet("/Homework2/MyNotes")
public class MyNotes extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void init() throws ServletException
    {

        if (getServletContext().getAttribute("cs320.hw2.Note") == null)
            getServletContext().setAttribute("cs320.hw2.Note", new ArrayList<User>());



        try
        {
            Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );
        }
        catch( ClassNotFoundException e )
        {
            throw new ServletException( e );
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String user = (String) session.getAttribute("CurrentUser");
        List<Notes> entries = (List<Notes>) getServletContext().getAttribute(
                "cs320.hw2.Note");

        if (user == null) {
            // User isn't authenticated
            response.sendRedirect("Login");
            return;
        }
        else {


             Connection c = null;
                try
                {
                    String host = "";
                    String port = "";
                    String dbName = "";
                    String username = "";
                    String password = "";

                    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;

                    c = DriverManager.getConnection( url, username, password );
                    Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
                    String sname = (String)session.getAttribute("name");
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "select * from entry    where name ='"+sname+"'");


                    while( rs.next() )
                    {
                            int id          = rs.getInt("id");
                            String name     = rs.getString("name");
                            String note     = rs.getString("note");
                            String title    = rs.getString("title");

                            Notes entry = new Notes(id, name, note, title);
                            entries.add(entry);
                    }

                    request.setAttribute("entries", entries);

                    request.getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/homework2/MyNotes.jsp" ).forward(
                         request, response );

                    for (Notes u : entries) {
                        System.out.println("id " + u.id + "name:  " + u.name + "Note:  "
                                + u.note + "title:  " + u.title);
                    }
                }
                catch( SQLException e )
                {
                    throw new ServletException( e );
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if( c != null ) c.close();
                    }
                    catch( SQLException e )
                    {
                        throw new ServletException( e );
                    }
                }


            }   

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,          IOException {

        }

     }
```

my jsp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>MyNotes</title>
</head>
<body>

<p align="right">Hello, ${sessionScope.CurrentUser}!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="Logout">Logout</a></p>
<span>JOT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="MyNotes">My Notes</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="NewNote.jsp">New</a></span>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<table border=1px>
  <tr><th>Titles</th></tr>
<c:forEach items="${entries}" var="entry">
  <tr>
    <td>${entry.title}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>


<p><a href="NewNote.jsp">New Note</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `entries` variable is created and stored in the ServletContext, i.e. is the same for the whole app (as the servlets, and thus their contexts, are always singletons).

Remove the

```
if (getServletContext().getAttribute("cs320.hw2.Note") == null)
    getServletContext().setAttribute("cs320.hw2.Note", new ArrayList<User>());
```

lines from the `init()` method, and replace

```
List<Notes> entries = (List<Notes>) getServletContext().getAttribute("cs320.hw2.Note");
```

with

```
List<Notes> entries = new ArrayList<Notes>();
```

in the `doGet()` method. You will have allways new empty list of entries to fill with the values obtained from the DB.